# why does changing "module -> rename to" attribute in .gwt.xml file give error

Tags: gwt, browser-history, gwt-2.4

I am able to create and run a simple GWT application by creating all the files myself. It works fine and I am able to see the correct display.

I tried playing around the code to enhance my knowledge. What I noticed is that, once I run my app with say **module rename to** value "**testhistory**" it works fine.

But after that if I change **rename to**'s value to say "**historytokentest**" the app gives errors like "Unable to find '**testhistory.gwt.xml**' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?"

If I change the **rename to**'s value back to "**testhistory**" it again works fine.

Can anyone clear whether there is any relation between **entryPoint class name**, .**gwt.xml** file name, **module rename to**'s value & also **project name**. Can they be changed in the future? (I know its not good to do so but just clearing doubts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the `rename-to`, it'll change the name of the output files, so you have to update your `<script>` tag in your HTML host page (from `src="testhistory/testhistory.nocache.js"` to `src="historytokentest/historytokentest.nocache.js"`). You don't have to change anything else.

Comment: that was a nice answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be changed. There will not be any problem if you change the project.

If you want to change/rename your entry point make sure that you are doing it at [modulename].gwt.xml also. Mostly few smarter IDE's will take care of this once you do rename.

Same way for module name changing you have to change it in host page. Nothing extra than that.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I am using History.newItem(someTokenString) but it doesn't fire onValueChange() for the first time. If I use History.fireCurrentHistoryState then I am able to call; but according to google docs History.newItem(someTokenString) should have called. Im using Chrome for dev mode.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling  History.newItem(someTokenString) after adding value change handler? Just incase if you are doing it before it will not work.

Comment: Im using somethng like this. Im sure Dinesh.

public void onModuleLoad()
 {
  History.addValueChangeHandler(this);
  //some code
         History.newItem(startToken,true);
          //some code
          }